# Best approach for returing an object reference in a function that can fail

Tags: c++

Im working on a little code for a queue that allows you to wait for input to be available.
Now, std::queue has the front function, which returns a reference to the top object, and I want to stick to a similar design.
The problem is, I want to allow the option to wait for X milliseconds for input to be available. That means that I also must return some status about the waiting (lets say, true for success, false for timeout). I can do it in 2 ways:

```
std::pair<bool, T&> frontWait(const std::chrono::milliseconds& timeout);
```

which I dont really like for some reason, its just really differs from the other function signatures, which either return T&, bool, or nothing.
Or i can have something like:

```
T& frontWait(const std::chrono::milliseconds& timeout, bool& waitResult);
```

which I dont really like either.

Perhaps there is an approach I missed? (throwing an exception on timeout doesnt sound good to me, since its not really an exception at all), If not, which of the approaches would be better?

Comment: What about `bool frontWait(const std::chrono::milliseconds& timeout, T& result)`? Or instead of returning a reference, return a pointer that could be `nullptr`.

Comment: can I set result to be a reference to the actual front object instead of copying the object into result?

Comment: Ah, I see. Not with my first suggestion, no, although you could change the parameter type to be `T*&` or `T**`, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider [`boost::optional<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

```
boost::optional<T&> frontWait(const std::chrono::milliseconds& timeout);
```

At the call site:

```
boost::optional<T&> result = frontWait(500);
if (result) {
    // Note the syntax similar to pointers, but boost::optional is not a pointer,
    // as you can read from its documentation.
    // Assume that doSomething has a prototype something like this:
    //   void doSomething(const T& x);
    // or:
    //   void doSomething(T& x);
    //
    doSomething(*result);
}
```

If, for some reason, you don't want to use `boost::optional`, I think another good option can be the simple bool-returning one, when the result value is returned to the caller via reference parameter:

```
bool frontWait(const std::chrono::milliseconds& timeout, T& result);
```

Comment: I ended up implementing a similar optional class, the second solution you proposed doesnt really fit because I wish to return a refenence to the object, not a copy of it. thanks!

Comment: @MosheMagnes: You're welcome. As a good Stackoverflow citizen, you may want to upvote _all_ the replies that you found helpful, and mark the best one as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Boost Optional. You don't need to use it. You could implement your own if you needed to.

As I recall, it'd work something like:

```
optional<T&> frontWait(const std::chrono::milliseconds &timeout)

auto response = frontWait(1000);
if(response) dosomething(response.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the obvious solution: return a pointer instead of a reference. A null pointer means the operation didn't succeed.

I'm not advocating this over other techniques, but that's the way things were done back in the old days.